# Solve the following equation for x assuming all constants are non-zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x}{a} + \frac{x}{3a} = 4 - x$$

I've tried and came out with x= 12a+4a, which is wrong. I know the answer, which is $$\frac{12a}{4 + 3a}$$ 
I just seem to not be able to figure out the work behind it. I got the answer from the back of the book. I would like to see the problem worked out the long way, as in how I tried solving it.

$$\frac{x}{a} + \frac{x}{3a} = 4 - x \ \Rightarrow \ \frac{x}{a} + x = 12a + 3ax \ \Rightarrow \ x + x - x = 12a + 4a \ \Rightarrow \ x = 12a + 4a$$

Comment: please delete a half of the equality signs. Your $\frac x a +x$ should be $3x+x$. Your $+3ax$ should be $-3ax$.

Comment: I still don't understand. I get what you said, but not the whole problem. But two negatives equal a positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a \ne 0$, then

$\frac{x}{a} + \frac{x}{3a} = 4-x$

$\frac{3x}{3a} + \frac{x}{3a} = 4-x$  // $\frac{x}{a}\cdot\frac{3}{3}$

$\frac{3x+x}{3a} = 4-x$  //Fractions with same denominator are combined

$\frac{4x}{3a} = 4-x$

$4x = 12a - 3ax$ //Multiplying 3a on both sides

$4x + 3ax = 12a$ //Adding 3ax on both sides

$x(4 + 3a) = 12a$ //Taking out GCF, which is x

$x = \frac{12a}{4+3a}$ //Dividing (4+3a) from both sides.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Have a look at my edits to your answer. Everything is the same, except I added some LaTeX formatting.

Comment: On dividing 4+3a from both sides wouldn't you take it back to being negative? I guess sometimes going back and forth from negative to positive doesn't stand up.

Comment: @Zlacki I'm not certain I understand your question. The quantity $(4 + 3a)$  is not negative; it may be, depending on $a$'s value, but you can find that by solving for $a$. Does that clarify your question?

Answer (score 3):

it must be $$a\ne 0$$ multiplying by $$3a$$ we get $$4x=12a-3ax$$ or $$x(4+3a)=12a$$ if $$a=-\frac{4}{3}$$ then we have no solutions, in the other case we obtain $$x=\frac{12a}{4+3a}$$

Comment: I still don't get how you got the solution, I understand what you wrote. Could you solve the problem the way I wrote it up there, to see the problem worked out the long way?

Comment: W, can you explain your first step? There is certainly an error.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{x}{a} + \dfrac{x}{3a} + x = 4$

Taking x common:
$x(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{3a}+1)=4$

Can you go on from here?

EDIT:

$\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{3a} + 1 = \dfrac{3 + 1 + 3a}{3a}$

Hence $x = \dfrac{4}{\dfrac{4 + 3a}{3a}} = \dfrac{12a}{4 + 3a}$

Comment: No I don't understand.